# How to redirect based on HTTP Basic/Digest username in Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to create a configuration (.htaccess) where if two users navigate to the same URL with different HTTP Basic or HTTP Digest credentials, they will be redirected to a different URL. How could I achieve this with Apache mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

If the URL being requested is `/example-url` then in root `.htaccess` file, using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

# User 1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} =USER1
RewriteRule ^example-url$ /target-url-for-user-1 [R=302,L]

# User 2
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} =USER2
RewriteRule ^example-url$ /target-url-for-user-2 [R=302,L]
```

`USER1` and `USER2` are the case-sensitive usernames set during the authorization phase.